# Laravel Scout toSearchableArray() not being called?

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, toarray, laravel-scout

I have working search functionality on one of my models (Recipe) using Laravel Scout and TNTSearch: [teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver).

I want to add the same search functionality to a different model (Ingredient). I'm attempting to get search results back as an array by using `toSearchableArray().` For the sake of testing, I did the following in my model.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Ingredient extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    public $asYouType = true;

    public function recipes() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe');
    }    

    public function toSearchableArray()    
    {
        $array = $this->toArray();

        return $array;
    }
}
```

In my controller I am trying this:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $results = Ingredient::search($request->q)->get()->toArray();

    return $results;
}
```

However, I am still getting my data back as a collection. I am using a similar set up for my other model (Recipe) which does return an array of results, as expected.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Recipe extends Model
{

    use Searchable;

    public $asYouType = true;

    public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient');
    }

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $array = $this->toArray();

        return $array;
    }
}
```

Then, again, in the model:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $resultsrecipes = Recipe::search($request->q)->get()->load('tags', 'ingredients', 'images');

    return $resultsrecipes;
}
```

This works for the Recipe model, even without the `load()` function. I assume that the `toSearchableArray()` function in my Ingredient model is not being called. My question is how can I verify and fix this?

I tried resetting the queue worker by using `php artisan queue:restart,` tried flushing and adding the records but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out [php artisan scout:flush doesn't work with TNTSearch](https://github.com/laravel/scout/issues/101), so I had to remove the index file manually and run php artisan scout:import to refresh the Searchable settings for the new model.